# Text is highlighted when clicking on an item in an ActiveX Combobox. Possible to prevent?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX combobox in a sheet that shows all the months. When I click on "January" for example the text "January" gets highlighted. As if you could delete it by pressing delete. It doesn't do that if you use the Form combobox.

I want to get rid of the text highlighting of the selected item shown in the combobox textfield after selecting.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a property which controls the text selection but you could do something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.Visible = False
    ComboBox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```